# Pattern matching algorithm to find outliers from votes

Tags: c#, algorithm, pattern-matching

I am trying to find a pattern matching algorithm that can be implemented using C# for this problem. Users have different attributes (in this example A, B, C and D). Users can share the same attribute as other users and you can search and filter for these attributes to find users. I am trying to implement an algorithm that can be used to remove users that are outliers based on their attributes. A user is considered as an outlier if you can combine the attributes to pinpoint a single user.

Below I am describing three different scenarios that I am looking for this pattern matching algorithm to detect what user(s) to remove because they can be pinpointed based on the combination of attributes available. For each scenario an X means that the user has this attribute.

**Scenario 1**

User 4 is an outlier because it has A,B,C and all other users have A,B,C,D. By combining all users with A,B,C you will get all users. By combining A,B,C,D you will get all except for User 4 which means this user must be removed.

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | X | X | X | X |
| User 2 | X | X | X | X |
| User 3 | X | X | X | X |
| User 4 | X | X | X |  |

**Scenario 2**

User 2 is an outlier because it has only D and all other users have A,B,C. User 2 needs to be removed.

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | X | X | X |  |
| User 2 |  |  |  | X |
| User 3 | X | X | X |  |
| User 4 | X | X | X |  |

**Scenario 3**

This scenario has no outliers as you cannot combine any combinations of A,B,C,D to pinpoint a single user. No users needs to be removed.

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | X | X |  |  |
| User 2 |  |  |  | X |
| User 3 |  |  | X |  |
| User 4 | X | X |  |  |

**Update to original question:**

The answer provided does in fact work for Scenario 1-3. I just realized I missed a key aspect of this problem and that is for multiple outliers based on different set of attributes. For this I will share a scenario 4 that is not covered by this.

**Scenario 4**

This scenario has two outliers (User 3 and User 6). This is because you can combine A,B,C to pinpoint User 3 as you know that the other users do not share the same attributes. The same goes for User 6 that can be pinpointed by combining D,E,F.

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | X | X | X |  |  |  |
| User 2 | X | X | X |  |  |  |
| User 3 | X | X |  |  |  |  |
| User 4 |  |  |  | X | X | X |
| User 5 |  |  |  | X | X | X |
| User 6 |  |  |  | X | X |  |

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `IEquatable<User>` to be able to use `GroupBy`. Then count each group and check if it's size is exactly `allUsers.Count - 1`. Then you know the other group is a single outlier:

```
public class User: IEquatable<User>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool A { get; set; }
    public bool B { get; set; }
    public bool C { get; set; }
    public bool D { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as User);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(A, B, C, D);
    }

    public bool Equals(User? other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return A == other.A && B == other.B && C == other.C && D == other.D;
    }
}
```

Now you can use `GroupBy` and for efficiency an `ILookup<int, List<User>>`:

```
ILookup<int, List<User>> countUserLookup = allUsers
    .GroupBy(u => u)
    .ToLookup(g => g.Count(), g => g.ToList());
User outlier = null;
// now check if there is a group that contains exactly allUsers.Count-1 duplicates
if (countUserLookup[allUsers.Count - 1].Any())
{
    // this count1-group always contains a single User: the outlier
    outlier = countUserLookup[1].First()[0];
}
```

Here are your users, tested all scenarios successfully, this is scenario 2:

```
List<User> allUsers = new()
{
    new User()
    {
        Name = "User1",
        A = true,
        B = true,
        C = true,
        D = false
    },
    new User()
    {
        Name = "User2",
        A = false,
        B = false,
        C = false,
        D = true,
    },
    new User()
    {
        Name = "User3",
        A = true,
        B = true,
        C = true,
        D = false,
    },
    new User()
    {
        Name = "User4",
        A = true,
        B = true,
        C = true,
        D = false,
    }
};
```

---

Update: Since you have changed the logic, now multiple outliers are possible and it seems that it just matters if a User is "alone", so has no duplicates, that is even simpler:

```
ILookup<int, List<User>> countUserLookup = allUsers
    .GroupBy(u => u)
    .ToLookup(g => g.Count(), g => g.ToList());
List<User> outliers = countUserLookup[1].SelectMany(list => list).ToList();
```

Maybe you need to check first if there is at least one non-outlier:

```
bool hasDuplicates = countUserLookup[2].Any();
```

Comment: thanks! this actually works great for my original question. i realized that i missed a key aspect about having multiple outliers based on different attribute sets. any idea how you would solve that? my first initial thought would be to break this up to multiple maps (using intersection perhaps?) and then use your approach to  find outliers in each map

Comment: @alkesos: this rule is not clear enough for me. With this every user can be an outlier. Can you provide a clear rule as text when multiple users are outliers in a given set of users? Maybe this: an outlier is a user which has no other user with the same properties?

Comment: @alkesos: look at my update